# How to extract value from SchemaTypes.Double mongoDB in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
lat: Double { _bsontype: 'Double', value: '77.7485988' }
```

currently my object is coming as above.
I need to get 77.7485988 from the object.

In mongoDB the schema for this is

```
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);
Start_lat:{
        type : SchemaTypes.Double,
        required: true
    }
```

How to get the value from the object?

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Object is of `bsontype` which is similar to the type of `_id`.

You can use `.valueOf()` to get the value, which is similar to getting `_id` value as `string` from ObjectId.

In your case it should be,

```
lat.valueOf();
```